# .htaccess URL rewriting - pages are opening with URL and without URL rewriting even if URL rewriting rules are present in .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need help about URL rewriting for image gallery for site.

This is problem, I needed to change hosting so I moved site to another server and there was problem because when it was transfered to that new server site worked without url rewriting, even if .htaccess file was present.
After few days problem is solved and my links look nice again. But search engines crawled my site in time when URL rewriting in .htaccess was not working somehow, so same pages are indexed in both ways, with nice URL and with out URL rewriting.
Like I said links are ok now, but there are a lot of results in data base of search engines which are still opening like that.

Normal fine links produced by CMS image gallery look like this:

```
http://www.mysite.net/Category/Subcategory/Item-name.html
```

But, in search engine data base there are still a lot of results witout URL rewriting, with links like this:

```
http://www.mysite.net/show.php?cat=Category&sub_cat=Subcategory&img=Item-name
```

Example:

If anyone try to open page it will be opened in both ways, practically you can see the same page opening this:

```
http://www.mysite.net/Category/Subcategory/Item-name.html
```

and this

```
http://www.mysite.net/show.php?cat=Category&sub_cat=Subcategory&img=Item-name
```

Can you help me with some SEO friendly URL redirect rules

This is part of my .htaccess file related to image gallery.

---

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

######## Begin - URL rewriting for image gallery ########

## For showig category of item
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ showcat.php?cat=$1 [L]

## For showig subcategory of item
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ showcat.php?cat=$1&subcat=$2 [L]

## For showig item
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*).html$ show.php?cat=$1&sub_cat=$2&img=$3 [L]

## For latest items
RewriteRule ^latest-page-(.*)/$ latest.php?page=$1 [L]

## For top rated items
RewriteRule ^top/page/(.*)/$ top.php?page=$1 [L]

## For show most rated - most clicked - most downloaded and most searched items
RewriteRule ^most-rated.html$ showmost.php?type=1 [L]
RewriteRule ^most-clicked.html$ showmost.php?type=2 [L]
RewriteRule ^most-downloaded.html$ showmost.php?type=3 [L]
RewriteRule ^most-Searched.html$ showmost.php?type=4 [L]

######## Begin - URL rewriting for image gallery ########
```

---

---

**Still, I can not get just this kind of links:**

```
http://www.mysite.net/Category/Subcategory/Item-name.html
```

**I tried your solution, like this:**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

######## Begin - URL rewriting for image gallery ########

## For showig category of item
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ showcat.php?cat=$1 [L]

## For showig subcategory of item
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ showcat.php?cat=$1&subcat=$2 [L]

## For showig item
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*).html$ show.php?cat=$1&sub_cat=$2&img=$3 [L]

## this section should be inserted just after the showing item rule above
#if the query string has cat, sub_cat and Img
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat=(.+)&sub_cat=(.+)&img=(.+)$ [NC]
#and it is for resource show.php, then 301 redirect to Keyword rich URL
RewriteRule ^show\.php$ http://www.mysite.net/%1/%2/%3.html [NC,L,R=301]

## For latest items
RewriteRule ^latest-page-(.*)/$ latest.php?page=$1 [L]

## For top rated items
RewriteRule ^top/page/(.*)/$ top.php?page=$1 [L]

## For show most rated - most clicked - most downloaded and most searched items
RewriteRule ^most-rated.html$ showmost.php?type=1 [L]
RewriteRule ^most-clicked.html$ showmost.php?type=2 [L]
RewriteRule ^most-downloaded.html$ showmost.php?type=3 [L]
RewriteRule ^most-Searched.html$ showmost.php?type=4 [L]

######## End - URL rewriting for image gallery ########
```

And now, I can access the same page with this normal URL:

```
http://www.mysite.net/Category/Subcategory/Item-name.html
```

And, I guess because of your new URL redirection rule now URL like this:

```
http://www.mysite.net/show.php?cat=Category&sub_cat=Subcategory&img=Item-name
```

is redirected to this:

```
http://www.mysite.net/Item-name.html?cat=Category&sub_cat=Subcategory&img=Item-name
```

But, you sure know that I wish just this URL:

```
http://www.mysite.net/Category/Subcategory/Item-name.html
```

Comment: Does google also index the urls with `/Category/...`? If so the easiest would be to just rename `show.php` to `show2.php` and change the rewiterules accordingly. Google will then receive a 404 for the old urls and remove them from their index.

Comment: If I rename show.php to show2.php and If that would work fine, I will probably lose visitors coming from search engines because they will then receive 404 error too, if I am right?

Comment: Another reason to redirect the URLs is to preserve your search engine ranking, which will be transferred to your new URLs when you use a 301.

Comment: I modified answer below to remove the original querystring params. You just need to add a`?` to the end of the redirect URL. i.e. `RewriteRule ^show\.php$ http://www.mysite.net/%1/%2/%3.html?  [NC,L,R=301]`

Comment: Thanks, that works fine now, it redirect ugly URL pages to normal URL pages. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If search engines indexed your site with the old URLs and you have since changed them to keyword rich URLs, then the correct way to let them know to use the new ones is to 301 redirect requests for the old URLs to the new ones.

Edit your current .htaccess file and place the section to redirect the old URLs to the new ones just after the showing item rule, as below.

```
## For showig item
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*).html$ show.php?cat=$1&sub_cat=$2&img=$3&rewrite=true [L]

## this section should be inserted just after the showing item rule above
#if the query string has cat, sub_cat and Img
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat=(.+)&sub_cat=(.+)&img=(.+)$ [NC]
#and it is for resource show.php, then 301 redirect to Keyword rich URL
RewriteRule ^show\.php$ http://www.mysite.net/%1/%2/%3.html? [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: I think this creates a infinite redirect loop.

Comment: it might :-). In case it does, I added an extraneous query string param in the Rewrite to prevent it. Thanks for noticing this.